# Can't detect or use Scanner Epson perfection v3790 in Elementary OS

Tags: drivers, hardware, printer

I have a Epson perfection v370, it isn't detected by xsane but in the terminal it does appear. Searching around I got to open xsane as root and then I got it working but it leaves it as a file that I don't have permission to use normally. 
What bothers me is why I can't use or detect a scanner as administrator and as root I do.
If someone knows how to solve this? It's really breaking my head.

Yes I use ElementaryOS

Greetings

Comment: Please try ` sudo adduser user_name scanner`, reboot and try scanning as a normal user (replace user_name with your user name). https://superuser.com/questions/298298/scanning-only-works-under-sudo-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks @VladPop the thing is that I'm already user in scanner. Entered the page you linked, and then an other that was in german, very interesting but too difficult. But I will try some other things in this page you linked. If something works I will write it here. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

I have Epson V300 and I have solved it by downloading Linux utility from Epson:

http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=gt-f720&version=2.30.4

It just worked :-)